# Code formatting in Swift to use the UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession function

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm new to Swift code formatting and I'm trying to figure out how to use the UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccess function.  Here's how the function is declared in Swift:

```
func UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(_ enable: Bool,
                                         _ completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)!)
```

In Objective-C I would have used it as follows:

```
UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(YES, ^(BOOL didSucceed) {
        if (didSucceed ) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
```

Any help with the syntax is appreciated.

Comment: It's the same as in objective-c, except in swift format. Which part are you having trouble with? Code formatting or actually getting it to work?

Comment: It's the code formatting - I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(true){
    success in
    println("Request guided access success \(success)")
}
```

`YES` is not valid in swift (use `true`/`false`), and if the last parameter of a function is a closure, you can use trailing closure syntax as shown above. `success` is the argument passed into the completion block.